# Multiple Slaves with multiple Users

Tags: jenkins, plugins, master-slave, jenkins-cli

I have to run some agents on multiple Windows clients. (Windows Server 2012R2).

The agent must run with a specific user. Is there any option to run a job with multiple Windows users on the same slave?

For example:

PC 1 logged on user: bob, jimmy, jane (3 different jobs with 3 different users)

Comment: Can you create several jenkins slave using different credentials and same host?
This works fine at linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One slave will have one windows credential. (You may try '[run as](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx)', but that is bit complicated)

Another option is to run jenkins slave process  with different windows user accounts. I use [jnlp](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Launch+Java+Web+Start+slave+agent+via+Windows+Scheduler) or [swarm agent](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin).

Comment: Hi Jayan,  thank you for the fast reply.
I'm running 2 jenkins nodes on the same maschine. I have to  do some special config, but you answer was really helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: @ Dotapiskota: You may add (edit this answer or your own answer)  your configuration details.  That will help someone with similar requirements.